# How to replace occurrences of ' apostrophe in a string and then create a URL swift

Tags: string, swift, url, audio

How would I replace and apostrophe in a string with another string? I have tried stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString but it doesn't recognise the apostrophe. I then need a replacement so it can be recognised by a URL

```
var name = "can't.wav"
name = name.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("'", withString: "%27") // i read somewhere that %27 might be ok in a URL, but not really sure.// %27 not needed.

let soundPath = (NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath! as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent(name)

// right now this returns xxx.app/canE2%80%99t.wav - I want it to return xxx.app/can't.wav
```

I then want to use this URL to play a sound

```
if checkValidation.fileExistsAtPath(soundPath) {
let soundURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(soundPath)                
            do {
                self.player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundURL)
                player.prepareToPlay()
                player.volume = 1.0
                player.play()

            } catch _ as NSError {
                print("file not found")
            }
        }
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Just a brief comment, make sure it's `var name` rather than `let` for a variable that you're modifying.

Comment: `but it doesn't recognise the apostrophe` What do you mean by that? I just tried and it returned "can%27t.wav", not "canE2%80%99t.wav". You must be doing something else.

Comment: UTF-8 `E2 80 99` is a "typographical" right quotation mark: ’ and *not* an apostrophe ' . You should double-check which character actually is used in your code and in the audio file name in your resources.

Comment: Genius. Nice one Martin R - they weren't apostrophe's at source! They looked like them but they were imposters! I would never have thought of that!. BTW the soundURL is ok with apostrophe's :-)

Comment: Thx @Phoen1xUK, I mistyped the question.

Comment: Thx for looking @EricD.